# Proving that a point is the maximum of a continuous function

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and it has a local maximum at $x_0$ and no other maximum or minimum points, then prove that $x_0$ is a global maximum.

I was hinted to use the fact that a continuous function at a closed area $[a,b]$ is bounded, but I don't see how this helps.

Thank you for the help

Comment: Intuition: In general, the reason that a local maximum may fail to be a global maximum is that somewhere else there is a higher value. But if the function "slopes down" from $x_0$ on both sides, and achieves a larger value somewhere else, then at some point it has to stop "sloping down" and start moving up. That will mean that there has to be a local minimum somewhere else (where the function stops going down and starts going up). To make this precise, assume there is a point $y$ where $f(y)\gt f(x_0)$. Think about what happens on $f$ on the interval $[x_0,y]$ (or $[y,x_0]$ if $y\lt x_0$).

Comment: Yea I was thinking that for each f(x) f(x+-1) has to be smaller then f(x). but the question specifically says to use the concept I wrote in the question and I don't see how that fits in...

Comment: Which is *why* I said to consider the finite closed interval $[x_0,y]$ (if $x_0\lt y$) or $[y,x_0]$ if $y\lt x_0$. The restriction of the function to such an interval is bounded, and so must have a maximum and a minimum. You are assuming that $f(y)\gt f(x_0)$, and you know that $f$ has a local maximum at $x_0$. Where is the minimum of $f$ on this interval, then? Is it a local minimum? (You are aiming for a contradiction, because you are assuming that there is a point where $f(y)\gt f(x_0)$, and you are trying to show there is no such point).

Comment: So if there was such a $y$ value then $[x_0,y]$ would contain a minimum and a maximum because it's bounded - but the question says that there is no other min/max point other then $x_0$? is that it?

Comment: That's the right start, but it's not "it" (the function $y=x$ has no local maximum and no local minimum, but it has maximum and minimum values on $[0,1]$; there is no contradiction). You still need to argue that the minimum value has to be somewhere *inside* the interval, in order to be able to conclude that that minimum value is actually a *local* minimum (*that* will give the contradiction).

Comment: Ok... so since $x_0$ is a local maximum then there is an area where all f(x) are smaller than it. in that case in order for there to be a y such that $f(y)>f(x)$ there must be a local minimum at $[x_0,y]$ and that is the contradiction - but I feel this is not entirely correct and not precise enough...

Comment: The first sentence tells you the *minimum* cannot be at $x_0$. You also know the minimum is not at $y$ (why?). So the minimum must be somewhere *inside* $(x_0,y)$. Call that point $z$. So $f(z)$ is the smallest value that $f$ takes in all of $[x_0,y]$, and hence in $(x_0,y)$. What does that mean? It means that $f$ has a *local* minimum at $z$ (because $f(z)$ is the smallest value that $f$ takes on the *open* interval $(x_0,y)$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that there is some point $a$ such that $f(a)>f(x_0)$. There’s no harm in assuming that $a<x_0$; the argument when $a>x_0$ is entirely similar. Consider how $f$ behaves on the interval $[a,x_0]$.

1. Must $f$ have a minimum on $[a,x_0]$? (This is where the hint is relevant.)
2. Can its minimum on $[a,x_0]$ occur at $x_0$?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but could you please elaborate? as you can see above I am kinda struggling :P

Comment: @Jhon: For (1): A continuous function on a closed interval is bounded, so it has a minimum somewhere on the interval. For (2): by the definition of *local maximum* there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(x_0)>f(x)$ for every $x\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$ except $x_0$ itself. Now pick $u\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0$; $f(u)<f(x_0)$, so the minimum of $f$ on $[a,x_0]$ isn’t at $x_0$, and it certainly isn’t at $a$ (why?), so it must be in $(a,x_0)$. But then it’s a minimum of $f$ not just on $[a,x_0]$ but on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Brian: Well, a *local* minimum of $f$...

Comment: @Arturo: I generally assume *local* unless *global* is specified, but I should indeed have specified it here.

Comment: @Brian: I agree generally; the possible point of confusion is that if one says "minimum on $\mathbb{R}$", that does suggest globality...

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that the function attained (at $x=b$) some value greater or equal to your local max (at $x=a$.) Then show that there is a local min between $a$ and $b$.

By the way, this isn't true for functions of more than one variable.